How to make function take certain combination of required params?
Say I have func
def get_chat(first_id, first_username, second_id, second_username):
   """Returns chat between first and second"""

To identify person either id or username is enough.
So I want to make the parameter optional if one is provided and required if second isn't provided. How to do it?
Of course I can do all params optional, but that seems a wrong way.

Is this question about type checking time or runtime restrictions?

Can you distinguish between an ID and username by type/value?

I would use two separate methods, get_chat_by_id and get_chat_by_username. Presumably, one of them would be a wrapper around the other (assuming you can get an id from a username and/or vice versa).

I would do abstraction of id and username to class Person object with find_person_by_id(id) and find_person_by_username(username). Then I would find a chat between two persons get_chat(a: Person, b: Person).

If you don't want to or cannot change the API, overload comes to rescue. And better mark all of those keyword-only, overloads will be much easier to write, and users will be less confused.

@chepner to counter upvotes count on your comment: there's a flaw in that approach. Using different types or a proxy type would be great, but two methods - nope. Currently it's possible to get chat by one id and one username, which is incompatible with your suggestion. That means you need a third method to cover such scenario, and three methods being a cross-product of possible argument kinds don't look like a perfect design.

Sure, if you need that flexibility.

Solution 1: id and username are different types
def get_chat(first_user: str | int, second_user: str | int):
    if isinstance(first_user, int):
        first_user_id = first_user
        first_user_name = get_name_from_id(first_user)
    else:
        first_user_name = first_user
        first_user_id = get_id_from_name(first_user)
    ...


Solution 2: universal
class User:
    @classmethod
    def from_id(cls, id: int) -> typing.Self:
        ...
    
    @classmethod
    def from_username(cls, username: str) -> typing.Self:
        ...

def get_chat(first_user: User, second_user: User):
    ...

These are the best I found, thanks to everyone who tried to help!
